# To delete a class name 'page' from the body

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, filtering, blacklist

I have created a Page Templates in WordPress. The body comes in the class as the following image. I want to remove 'page' class.

[image]

Comment: Relevant pages on WordPressDevelopment.SE: [Remove classes from body_class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/15850) and [Remove and add class with body_class() function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/250185) and [Remove Body Classes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/406747)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Wordpress Body Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799089/remove-wordpress-body-classes)

Comment: Relevant: [Remove class from my body tag. Wordpress. Genesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46977971/2943403) and [How to remove category class from post page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72511369/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove class from body tag with the help of filter. try below script.

```
function remove_body_classes( $wp_classes ) {
    $blacklist = array( 'page' );
    $wp_classes = array_diff( $wp_classes, $blacklist );
    return $wp_classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_body_classes', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if ( isset( $classes['your-class-name'] ) ) {
        unset( $classes['your-class-name'] );
    }
    return $classes;
} );

Answer (score 0):

Filter `body_class` using `array_search` as follow works for me:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    unset($classes[array_search('page', $classes)]);
    return $classes;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if ( isset( $classes['page'] ) ) {
        unset( $classes['page'] );
    }
    return $classes;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I wanted to do the particular for the one page.I have manually adopted the solution which is as follows.The directory path in my condition was wrong

```
function remove_body_classes( $wp_classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'inc/home-template-page.php' ) ) {
        $page = array( 'page' );
        $wp_classes = array_diff( $wp_classes, $page );
    }
    return $wp_classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_body_classes', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add this script at the end of the Page Template that you have created .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             $=jQuery;
           $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "body" ).removeClass( "page" )
    });
 </script>
```